# How to get the value of "ReferenceNumber" from data json object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Following is my code. How can I access `ReferenceNumber` from it?

```js
{
  "errors": [],
  "data": [
    [
      {
        "$": {
          "Type": "Shipment Confirmation Advice",
          "xmlns": "urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x50065"
        },
        "ReceiptAuthorization": [
          {
            "DepositorCode": "A400",
            "ReferenceNumber": "00-001",
            "ShipmentDate": "12/07/18",
            "ExpArrivalDate": null,
            "ShipFrom": {
              "ShipFromCode": null,
              "ShipFromName": "AAWS",
              "ShipFromName2": null,
              "ShipFromAddr1": null,
              "ShipFromAddr2": null,
              "ShipFromCity": null,
              "ShipFromState": null,
              "ShipFromZip": null,
              "ShipFromCountry": null
            },
            "Carrier": {
              "CarrierCode": "FDXE",
              "CarrierName": "Federal Express Corporation"
            },
            "Container": null,
            "ProNumber": null,
            "Warehouse": "MAIN",
            "HdrUser1": null,
            "HdrUser2": null,
            "HdrUser3": null,
            "HdrUser4": null,
            "HdrUser5": "PURCHASE ORDER",
            "ShipFromRef": null,
            "TotalQtyDeclared": "2,000",
            "Temperature": "0",
            "MasterDocumentNumber": null,
            "RectLine": [
              {
                "ItemNumber": "AFRIB-30",
                "DeclaredQty": "1,000",
                "UOM": "EACH",
                "ItemDesc1": "AFRICAN BIG BOOK SOFT COVER",
                "ItemDesc2": null,
                "SubPart1Number": null,
                "SubPart2Number": null,
                "LineReference": null,
                "LineUser1": null,
                "LineUser2": null,
                "LineUser3": null,
                "LineUser4": null,
                "LineUser5": null,
                "Pack1": "20",
                "Pack2": null,
                "UnitWeight": "0.85",
                "TareWeight": null,
                "Length": null,
                "Width": null,
                "Height": null,
                "Volume": null,
                "Category": "PRINTED MATERIALS",
                "Lot": null,
                "CodeDate": null,
                "GrsWeight": "850",
                "NetWeight": null,
                "DetailRef": null,
                "SubLot": null,
                "TagID": null,
                "Attribute1": null,
                "Attribute2": null,
                "Attribute3": null,
                "Attribute4": null,
                "Attribute5": null,
                "Attribute6": null
              },
              {
                "ItemNumber": "ARMEB-30",
                "DeclaredQty": "1,000",
                "UOM": "EACH",
                "ItemDesc1": "ARMENIAN BIG BOOK",
                "ItemDesc2": null,
                "SubPart1Number": null,
                "SubPart2Number": null,
                "LineReference": null,
                "LineUser1": null,
                "LineUser2": null,
                "LineUser3": null,
                "LineUser4": null,
                "LineUser5": null,
                "Pack1": "20",
                "Pack2": null,
                "UnitWeight": "0.85",
                "TareWeight": null,
                "Length": null,
                "Width": null,
                "Height": null,
                "Volume": null,
                "Category": "PRINTED MATERIALS",
                "Lot": null,
                "CodeDate": null,
                "GrsWeight": "850",
                "NetWeight": null,
                "DetailRef": null,
                "SubLot": null,
                "TagID": null,
                "Attribute1": null,
                "Attribute2": null,
                "Attribute3": null,
                "Attribute4": null,
                "Attribute5": null,
                "Attribute6": null
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "DepositorCode": "A400",
            "ReferenceNumber": "PO000258",
            "ShipmentDate": "07/12/18",
            "ExpArrivalDate": null,
            "ShipFrom": {
              "ShipFromCode": null,
              "ShipFromName": "Pending RFQ",
              "ShipFromName2": null,
              "ShipFromAddr1": null,
              "ShipFromAddr2": null,
              "ShipFromCity": null,
              "ShipFromState": null,
              "ShipFromZip": null,
              "ShipFromCountry": null
            },
            "Carrier": {
              "CarrierCode": null,
              "CarrierName": null
            },
            "Container": null,
            "ProNumber": null,
            "Warehouse": "MAIN",
            "HdrUser1": null,
            "HdrUser2": null,
            "HdrUser3": null,
            "HdrUser4": null,
            "HdrUser5": "PURCHASE ORDER",
            "ShipFromRef": null,
            "TotalQtyDeclared": "1",
            "Temperature": "0",
            "MasterDocumentNumber": null,
            "RectLine": {
              "ItemNumber": "B-1",
              "DeclaredQty": "1",
              "UOM": "EACH",
              "ItemDesc1": "Big Book Hardcover 4th Edition",
              "ItemDesc2": null,
              "SubPart1Number": null,
              "SubPart2Number": null,
              "LineReference": "1",
              "LineUser1": null,
              "LineUser2": null,
              "LineUser3": null,
              "LineUser4": null,
              "LineUser5": null,
              "Pack1": "20",
              "Pack2": null,
              "UnitWeight": "1.6",
              "TareWeight": null,
              "Length": null,
              "Width": null,
              "Height": null,
              "Volume": null,
              "Category": "PRINTED MATERIALS",
              "Lot": null,
              "CodeDate": null,
              "GrsWeight": "1.6",
              "NetWeight": null,
              "DetailRef": null,
              "SubLot": null,
              "TagID": null,
              "Attribute1": null,
              "Attribute2": null,
              "Attribute3": null,
              "Attribute4": null,
              "Attribute5": null,
              "Attribute6": null
            }
          },
          {
            "DepositorCode": "A400",
            "ReferenceNumber": "PO000254",
            "ShipmentDate": "07/12/18",
            "ExpArrivalDate": null,
            "ShipFrom": {
              "ShipFromCode": null,
              "ShipFromName": "Pending RFQ",
              "ShipFromName2": null,
              "ShipFromAddr1": null,
              "ShipFromAddr2": null,
              "ShipFromCity": null,
              "ShipFromState": null,
              "ShipFromZip": null,
              "ShipFromCountry": null
            },
            "Carrier": {
              "CarrierCode": null,
              "CarrierName": null
            },
            "Container": null,
            "ProNumber": null,
            "Warehouse": "MAIN",
            "HdrUser1": null,
            "HdrUser2": null,
            "HdrUser3": null,
            "HdrUser4": null,
            "HdrUser5": "PURCHASE ORDER",
            "ShipFromRef": null,
            "TotalQtyDeclared": "1",
            "Temperature": "0",
            "MasterDocumentNumber": null,
            "RectLine": {
              "ItemNumber": "B-1",
              "DeclaredQty": "1",
              "UOM": "EACH",
              "ItemDesc1": "Big Book Hardcover 4th Edition",
              "ItemDesc2": null,
              "SubPart1Number": null,
              "SubPart2Number": null,
              "LineReference": "1",
              "LineUser1": null,
              "LineUser2": null,
              "LineUser3": null,
              "LineUser4": null,
              "LineUser5": null,
              "Pack1": "20",
              "Pack2": null,
              "UnitWeight": "1.6",
              "TareWeight": null,
              "Length": null,
              "Width": null,
              "Height": null,
              "Volume": null,
              "Category": "PRINTED MATERIALS",
              "Lot": null,
              "CodeDate": null,
              "GrsWeight": "1.6",
              "NetWeight": null,
              "DetailRef": null,
              "SubLot": null,
              "TagID": null,
              "Attribute1": null,
              "Attribute2": null,
              "Attribute3": null,
              "Attribute4": null,
              "Attribute5": null,
              "Attribute6": null
            }
          },
          {
            "DepositorCode": "A400",
            "ReferenceNumber": "PO000253",
            "ShipmentDate": "07/12/18",
            "ExpArrivalDate": null,
            "ShipFrom": {
              "ShipFromCode": null,
              "ShipFromName": "Pending RFQ",
              "ShipFromName2": null,
              "ShipFromAddr1": null,
              "ShipFromAddr2": null,
              "ShipFromCity": null,
              "ShipFromState": null,
              "ShipFromZip": null,
              "ShipFromCountry": null
            },
            "Carrier": {
              "CarrierCode": null,
              "CarrierName": null
            },
            "Container": null,
            "ProNumber": null,
            "Warehouse": "MAIN",
            "HdrUser1": null,
            "HdrUser2": null,
            "HdrUser3": null,
            "HdrUser4": null,
            "HdrUser5": "PURCHASE ORDER",
            "ShipFromRef": null,
            "TotalQtyDeclared": "5",
            "Temperature": "0",
            "MasterDocumentNumber": null,
            "RectLine": {
              "ItemNumber": "AMHAP-2",
              "DeclaredQty": "5",
              "UOM": "EACH",
              "ItemDesc1": "Amharic - 44 Questions",
              "ItemDesc2": null,
              "SubPart1Number": null,
              "SubPart2Number": null,
              "LineReference": "1",
              "LineUser1": null,
              "LineUser2": null,
              "LineUser3": null,
              "LineUser4": null,
              "LineUser5": null,
              "Pack1": "250",
              "Pack2": null,
              "UnitWeight": "0.076",
              "TareWeight": null,
              "Length": null,
              "Width": null,
              "Height": null,
              "Volume": null,
              "Category": "PRINTED MATERIALS",
              "Lot": null,
              "CodeDate": null,
              "GrsWeight": "0.38",
              "NetWeight": null,
              "DetailRef": null,
              "SubLot": null,
              "TagID": null,
              "Attribute1": null,
              "Attribute2": null,
              "Attribute3": null,
              "Attribute4": null,
              "Attribute5": null,
              "Attribute6": null
            }
          },
          {
            "DepositorCode": "A400",
            "ReferenceNumber": "PO000260",
            "ShipmentDate": "07/12/18",
            "ExpArrivalDate": null,
            "ShipFrom": {
              "ShipFromCode": null,
              "ShipFromName": "Pending RFQ",
              "ShipFromName2": null,
              "ShipFromAddr1": null,
              "ShipFromAddr2": null,
              "ShipFromCity": null,
              "ShipFromState": null,
              "ShipFromZip": null,
              "ShipFromCountry": null
            },
            "Carrier": {
              "CarrierCode": null,
              "CarrierName": null
            },
            "Container": null,
            "ProNumber": null,
            "Warehouse": "MAIN",
            "HdrUser1": null,
            "HdrUser2": null,
            "HdrUser3": null,
            "HdrUser4": null,
            "HdrUser5": "PURCHASE ORDER",
            "ShipFromRef": null,
            "TotalQtyDeclared": "1",
            "Temperature": "0",
            "MasterDocumentNumber": null,
            "RectLine": {
              "ItemNumber": "B-1",
              "DeclaredQty": "1",
              "UOM": "EACH",
              "ItemDesc1": "Big Book Hardcover 4th Edition",
              "ItemDesc2": null,
              "SubPart1Number": null,
              "SubPart2Number": null,
              "LineReference": "1",
              "LineUser1": null,
              "LineUser2": null,
              "LineUser3": null,
              "LineUser4": null,
              "LineUser5": null,
              "Pack1": "20",
              "Pack2": null,
              "UnitWeight": "1.6",
              "TareWeight": null,
              "Length": null,
              "Width": null,
              "Height": null,
              "Volume": null,
              "Category": "PRINTED MATERIALS",
              "Lot": null,
              "CodeDate": null,
              "GrsWeight": "1.6",
              "NetWeight": null,
              "DetailRef": null,
              "SubLot": null,
              "TagID": null,
              "Attribute1": null,
              "Attribute2": null,
              "Attribute3": null,
              "Attribute4": null,
              "Attribute5": null,
              "Attribute6": null
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: is this a joke ? `sssssssssssssssssss..` ??

Comment: Do you want to get the ReferenceNumber recursively from the object?

Comment: it was put accidentally, please see the next code for answering,thank you

Comment: @ShubhamShirsat and can't you just edit the post to prevent other users to mark it for spam?

Comment: Yes Manikanta , i want that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with

```
jsonObject.data[0][0].ReceiptAuthorization[i].ReferenceNumber
```

where 
jsonObject is the json object and i is the array element which you want to know the ReferenceNumber.

Comment: @ShubhamShirsat to learn this kind of thing, I suggest you use Chrome (or another browser) DevTools. To answer you I used the devTools Console, I put a new var jsonObject like that you have posted and I try to access it with javascript command.  I hope I help :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider your total response as responseObj, then you can use the following code to get the "ReferenceNumber" from each object.

```
var detailsArray = responseObj.data.ReceiptAuthorization;
detailsArray.forEach(function(refObj){
  console.log(refObj.ReferenceNumber)
});
```